# What's wrong in this javascript code? (CLOSED)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make while user clicks on region at map (`#map-polska`), page scrolls to `#adresses` `div`, but it doesn't work with that code, and I can't solve it - where the problem lays..

```
$('#map-polska').cssMap({
  size: 500,
  agentsListId: '#addresses',
  onClick: function (e) {
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#addresses').offset().top
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens? Any error messages?

Comment: What doesnt work ? any errors ? also note that in your text you specify `#adresses` and in your code you specify `#addresses`

Comment: Does cssMap really take event callbacks ? That would be a strange name.

Comment: @ManseUK, @ Lee Taylor No error messages, it just stops to show map (without this code it shows) and before it I have this code. And .cssMap works  $(function($){
     $('#map-polska').cssMap({'size' : 500});
    });

 $('#map-polska').cssMap({ 'agentsListId' : '#addresses'});

Comment: Feel free to tell us what cssMap is; a plugin? something you wrote? Without knowing that how can we help you since its not clear if the onclick is an argument or if your code should look like @dystroy answer.

Comment: Anyways if you change your handler to just show an *alert*, what happens? eg `$('#map-polska').cssMap({ size: 500, agentsListId: '#addresses', onClick: function (e) { alert('clicked'); }});`

Comment: I think cssMap is a function, there is a line in code ;(function($){$.fn.cssMap=function

Comment: Does the function accept an onClick argument? What about the *alert* example I suggested?

Comment: @Chris Moutray - with alert it shows only links wich are supposed to be map, which means it doesn't work and no alert appears

Comment: @Chris Moutray as far as I know it must accept onClick argument, that's why I was thinking that maybe some bad syntax there

Comment: You can check for yourself if you can see the definition of the function

Comment: What makes you think it accepts an onClick arg?

Comment: In cssMap=function(options) there is 'onClick':function(e){} - does that means it should work with this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's `cssMap` but in order to conform to the usual jQuery model, your code should probably be :

```
$('#map-poland').click(function (e) {
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#addresses').offset().top
    }, 1500);
  }
).cssMap({
  size: 500,
  agentsListId: '#addresses'
});
```

But maybe what you want is :

```
$('#map-poland').click(function (e) {
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#addresses').offset().top
    }, 1500);
  }
).css(size: 500)
.attr('agentsListId', '#addresses');
```

By the way, [jquery's css function](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) accepts a map as parameter.

Comment: with this option it works, but previuosly when I was clicking at region and it showed only selected information and now it shows everything (that agentsListId with adresses was actually this info and in script it was defined like this _$(function(e){
    $('#map-polska').cssMap({'size' : 500});
    });

 $('#map-polska').cssMap({ 'agentsListId' : '#addresses'});_

Comment: actually it was a problem of conflict between jquery and mootols